# Spring boot on Heroku

Tags: spring, git, maven, heroku

I get the following Error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.15:revision (default) on project placebook: .git directory could not be found! Please specify a valid [dotGitDirectory] in your pom.xml -> [Help 1]`

Can someone Help me? The [dotGitDirectory] exists!!!

Comment: can you share pom.xml?

Comment: i fixed it by removing the git commit plugin from pom.xml. Thanks.

Comment: I've the same issue see https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/issues/279 but removing the plugin isn't an option

Comment: This seems to be a related issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173467/maven-cannot-find-git-dotgitdirectory

Comment: Thanks! I solved this already.